# Spring Data + Datanucleus + JPA Querying by Date

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, spring-data, datanucleus

Hi I have an application running on GAE with Spring + Spring Data + Datanucleus (JPA) and I need to query an entity by date and a enum.
I have some test cases and locally works as expected, also running the dev server in my local I get the expected results. When I deploy the same app in GAE that particular query throws an exception.

The query looks like the following one.

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.scheduleDate is not null and campaign.scheduleDate > ?1 and campaign.status in ('CREATED')")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart(final Date fromDate);
```

I also tried:

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.scheduleDate is not null and campaign.scheduleDate > ?1 and campaign.status in (?2)")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart(final Date fromDate, final Collection<CampaignStatus> status);
```

I modified the query to see if I can find the problem and seems that the comparison of the date and inequality operator ">" is the problematic. 
If I use equality operator "=" the query runs correctly but of course I don't get the expected results.

The Campaign entity is defined as follow:

```
@Entity
public class Campaign extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Basic
private String name;

@Column(nullable = true)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date scheduleDate;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CampaignStatus status;
...
...
}
```

The versions that I am using for Spring, Datanucleus and AppEngine:

- spring.version > 3.2.2.RELEASE
- spring.data.jpa.version > 1.3.5.RELEASE
- datanucleus.version > 3.1.4
- appengine.sdk.version > 1.7.5
- appengine.datanucleus.version > 2.1.2

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I've been testing different queries and I end in the conclusion that is not possible to mix the use of inequality and equality operator on different properties of an entity.
My tests were:

**WORKS**

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.scheduleDate is not null and campaign.scheduleDate > ?1")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart(final Date fromDate);
```

**WORKS**

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.status in ('CREATED')")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart();
```

**WORKS**

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.status = 'CREATED'")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart();
```

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.scheduleDate is not null and campaign.scheduleDate > ?1 and campaign.status in ('CREATED')")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart(final Date fromDate);
```

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
@Query("select campaign from Campaign campaign where campaign.scheduleDate is not null and campaign.scheduleDate > ?1 and campaign.status = 'CREATED'")
List<Campaign> scheduledPendingToStart(final Date fromDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do a >?1 for schedule date, it shouldn't grab the nulls anyway, so you don't need both I'd think.

Another way would be to just do a "status = 'CREATED'" and then order by date, making sure you skip the records you don't want (not optimal of course).

Normally the app engine datastore SHOULD support inequality and equality on different properties... it won't allow multiple inequality filters on multiple properties, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Restrictions_on_queries).  Can you copy the exception you receive?

Comment: Hi Julldar, yes, I was reading last night about the restriction of inequalities on different properties but i understand that this is not the case. Also I solved the query as you mention but filtering by scheduledate and with the results filter by status (not so nice but works), but I want to know if I am missing regarding query restrictions on GAE. As I mention in my original question, in my local the query works - only fails in prod. I ll try to add detail to the logs and post the stacktrace. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'll try to see what I can do myself trying to reproduce.  It IS very weird local and production don't behave the same way.  I'll let you know if I do find something else :)

Comment: Are you sure your datastore indexes match your query ? that's one thing that the development environment generates automatically for you, not the production one.